# Why is something considered wrong?

Tags: ethics

What is the underlying reason something is considered wrong? The only reason things are considered wrong is because they harm someone or something right? So if an action doesn't harm anyone or anything can it be considered wrong?

Comment: You have to consider also *laws* : something is "wrong" if it is contrary to laws.

Comment: That depends upon your perspective.  For Kant, a lie that does no harm is still wrong, because (to compromise the logic a bit) the principle behind it causes damage in other contexts, and condoning potentially dangerous behavior is in itself wrong, even if most instances do not, in fact, do harm.  His argument about eating too much meat is clearer: even if your own source of meat is carefully chosen to be humane, too high a volume causes the industry to become inhumane to its workers.  You should eat a sustainable quantity, that would not result in pressure to compromise.

Comment: This question is not about philosophy, but about *language*. You are asking: 'What do people usually mean when they say that a thing is wrong?'. This is perhaps an interesting question, although it has little to do with philosophy.

Comment: @M.leFou This is pretty much *the basic question* in ethics, so writing it off as not philosophical seems excessively dismissive.

Comment: @jobermark Hmm yes I think you're right. Not sure what I had in mind when I left that comment.

Comment: But no one has given you feedback on difficult questions yet.  The question is so broad that every major ethical theory would be an answer, right?  We are left with too daunting a task, speaking for each ethics in turn, and no one will answer.  The body outlines a given position, but takes the form of an 'Am I right?" question, which we also try to avoid.  You might want to ask who in philosophy does not hold the view that you are espousing here.  (The list of those who do is too long.)

Comment: Sure, a 19yo male consentually impregnates a 17yo, they get married, raise healthy kids & live happily ever after and the 19yo is a life time registered sex offender because the prosecution reasoned his action of having sex with a minor were wrong before a judge & the judge passed sentence accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Right and Wrong are cultural universals.  One of the characteristics of a cultural universal is that everybody on the planet agrees that there are concepts of "right" and "wrong," but they disagree on what is right and what is wrong.

Accordingly, there is no one answer to your question, other than to point out that your assertions, "The only reason things are considered wrong is because they harm someone or something right? So if an action doesn't harm anyone or anything can it be considered wrong?" are only true within ethical systems where they are true.  There are plenty of ethical systems where they are false.

Unfortunately, as Jobermark pointed out, this is really the fundamental question behind the entire philosophical discipline known as "ethics."  To merely *list* all of the ethical frameworks would be beyond the scope of an answer such as this, much less providing a critique of each one.  My recommendation would be to engage in your own study of ethics, on your own time.  My personal approach would be to start from the Wikipedia article on the topic, [Ethics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethics), and work from there, but you can use any study method which suits your style.

Answer (score 1):

Let's remember that the meaning of right and wrong will change from place to place and even over time within the same places. It is the way that the right and the wrong are percieved. The perception of those is passed through generations, that at some point had a line drawn between the two. For example, hurting someone is wrong, but many would agree that if that someone was hurting another person, then it would be right to hurt that someone to save that another person. People can also define something as wrong if it goes against their believes. In another aspect, something can also be wrong if it is not the ideal solution to a problem. For example, lets pretend that the answer to a math problem is a whole number with an infinite number of decimals; in this case, including just a few decimals would be an accepted answer. However, it would not be an accepted answer if only the whole number was included. Although the whole number is part of the answer, it would not be the expected answer. One can also think to be  right in his or her own self, but be wrong to the rest of the world. People can either not do wrong because they are afraid to be judged, or because they agree with what is defined as wrong. Nations many times will not agree on each other and define right and wrong differently; but yet, they have the power to judge within their own limits. The final answer to what is right and what is wrong can only be given by that who has the power to judge over the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Whether something ir right or wrong depends on the ethical conception of a certain person or institution. Now the reason why a person or institution would consider something is wrong may vary: Could be beacuse it harms someone (it's wrong to stab people), could be because it harms something valuable (it's wrong to burn the Mona Lisa), could be because it go against the laws, or tradition, or religion...